# Flex Layout - Text wrapping issue with 2 column layout

Tags: css, layout, flexbox

I have a 2 column layout such as the following:

**|--title--|--content--|**

The title is always going to be one word, hence one line, but content could extend into multiple lines. When that happens, it causes the title to wrap onto the second line, hence breaking the UI, like:

**|--ti---| |--cont-|**

**|--tle--| |--ent--|**

What I tried:
Giving `flex-wrap: no wrap` to title, and giving it a width. However that only works for cases with multiline content, hence unnecessarily adding width to the titles adjacent to single line content.

Their parent has the following CSS:

`display: flex;
width: 100%;
align-items: flex-start;
justify-content: space-between;`

How to fix the wrapping issue?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/njcs30g9/7/
You can see how `Child 2` is now split into 2 lines.

Comment: Can you please show a snippet where its happenning

Comment: I will try to recreate it on Fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `flex-shrink: 0` on child will prevent it from splitting.

More about [flex-shrink](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink).

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.child {
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>
    <span class='child-l'>Child</span>
    <span class='child-r'>2</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class='content'>
    These are multiple lines of content that expand into 2 lines and breaks the UI.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good lord! Thank you so much, saved me from pulling my hair out.